# Why I cannot break my implode in php?

Tags: php, explode, implode

I am trying to use implode after explode, and then break a line. For example,
blue white yellow, I want them in different lines. so I use the follow code to explode it first, and then implode the "," and then ""
But I don't have any problem break a line on explode, but it has a problem with implode, I spend a lot of time to search the answer, and I don't seem any wrong, what do i miss?

```
<?php
$color="blue white yellow";
$explode_color=explode(" ", $color);

$implode=array();
foreach($explode_color as $explode_colors){
    $implode[]=$explode_colors;
}

 $implode_color=implode(',', $implode);
 echo $implode_color."</br>";

?>
```

it echo out like blue,white,yellow on the same line but I want to break them in different line.

Comment: Just for argument's sake, you're missing a quote in `(" ", "$color)` - If you're using `(" ", "$color")` then change that in your question. It's throwing off syntax highlighting. Btw, the syntax is `<br/>` and not `</br>`.

Comment: If you want to have them separated by ',<br/>', then implode them with that string. Not just join them with a comma, then add a break tag after the string.

Answer (score 1):

You said you want to implode by `<br>` but then you are imploding by `','`. The following snippet will do what you wanted.

```
$color="blue white yellow";
echo implode("<br>", explode(" ", $color));
//⇒ blue<br>white<br>yellow
```

Answer (score 0):

This will achieve the required result but using the `preg_replace()` function.

```
$color="blue white yellow";

$colors =  preg_replace('/ /', '<br/>',$color);

echo $colors;
```

Result is

```
blue<br/>white<br/>yellow
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is

```
$color="blue white yellow";
$explode_color=explode(" ", "$color);
```

Please remove " from front of $color variable.

```
$color="blue white yellow";
$explode_color=explode(" ", $color);
```

implode function returns a string value so if you want to see colors in many lines then you will have to separate it with `<br/>` instead of comma (,). 
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one color per line so why don't you print then from array?

```
// Define colors
$colors = 'blue white yellow';

// Explode to array
$colorsArray = explode(' ', $colors);

// Print colors
foreach($colorsArray as $color){
    echo $color.'<br/>';
}
```

But if you really want to implode them again with `,`:

```
// Define colors
$colors = 'blue white yellow';

// Explode to array
$colorsArray = explode(' ', $colors);

// Print colors
foreach($colorsArray as $color){
    echo $color.'<br/>';
}

// Implode again - this time with comma
$colorsNew = implode(',', $colorsArray);

// Explode again and print
$colorsExploded = explode(' ', $colors);
foreach($colorsExploded as $color){
    echo $color.'<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unnecessarily convoluted/indirect to explode your string into an array and then implode it using `<br>` as glue.

Rather, just keep the data as a string and modify the delimiters.

You have static delimiting characters (a space), so `preg_replace` is overkill, just use `str_replace()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/fWJE3))

```
$color="blue white yellow";
echo str_replace(' ','<br>',$color);  // replace spaces with <br> tags

echo "\n\n---\n\n";

echo str_replace(' ',"\n",$color);  // this is what the rendered html will look like
```

Output:

```
// this is what the source code will look like
blue<br>white<br>yellow

---

// this is what the rendered html will look like
blue
white
yellow
```